# Combining two TypeScript object with the same keys & different properties?

Tags: typescript

I have two TypeScript objects with the same keys, but different properties.  I want to combine/merge the properties from one of the objects onto the other object.

```js
interface Stat<T, V> {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  formatValue: (params: { value: V; item: T }) => string;
}

type Currency = 'USD' | 'CAD';

interface Item {
  id: number;
  product: string;
  earnings: number;
  currency: Currency;
  // etc.
}

type Stats<T> = { [P in keyof T]: Stat<T, T[P]> };

// This is the first object that I'm interested in combining...
const items: Stats<Item> = {
  id: {
    name: 'ID',
    description: 'Unique identifier for a sales item.',
    formatValue: ({ value }) => String(value),
  },
  product: {
    name: 'Product',
    description: 'The name of the product sold.',
    formatValue: ({ value }) => value,
  },
  earnings: {
    name: 'Earnings',
    description: 'The dollar value earned in the appropriate currency.',
    formatValue: ({ value, item }) => Intl.NumberFormat('en-us', { style: 'currency', currency: item.currency }).format(value),
  },
  currency: {
    name: 'Currency',
    description: 'The currency used during the sale.',
    formatValue: ({ value }) => value,
  },
};

interface Column {
  width: number;
  align?: string;
}

type Columns<T> = { [P in keyof T]: Column };

// This is the second object that I'm interested in combining...
const columns: Columns<Item> = {
  id: { width: 50, align: 'right' },
  product: { width: 200 },
  earnings: { width: 100, align: 'right' },
  currency: { width: 75 },
};
```

Alternatively, I've created a [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjmAPAFQDTIBqAfMgN4CwAUMsiHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDc1tACYQ2CLgAcwwAPYhWHLiD4DkMaVAaZCcADYBXFsgAU4uFEZtWZZADddB1oV7JgkBqxzIAvgEpkAXlIFHn4qL2pqMABPcRQAYT0oKAgQBCiA5AByAFVUABFM5AAfLLiAQQLQ6lBIWEQUAEk3chVgQVYQPQYAI2hQ2nEoaUE9BDB5ThCVCDMQHks6Lt6ofuQEROTUqNYEpJS01YB6Q+QIMAQAOmpwqkiYlHRMNlxSf3JkAG0ABRcQZABrCBRaQwZA4AC6rEe2HwYO+4NIXiqVGOYIAFsA2C4sWA0SgYMAoBxkNJugArCBjZC4zDIBqZBi-WoiSCCX5raQ9UA8C686gIWTE1wQBgLaHPJoi14tGgudoy2i0ehMViZBoFPAqIQiMTASQyORZbJzACOBjlKSkBOgqnUyDg7F0IhcbgumU1stoag0WnshiM1js+hQvgCpHQim4RiDBh8HtoXnjyEGw1G4wViuVhkyXyGIzG7q1yGEogkUlkqpweLojBQIOp1ZT+bA7GkOkEbqTXvUmjA2mDrADtj93j8gWHwaTiems3mViLWdVAFFZ0o2IXPcWdWWDZXq4I2zozBPzTMoCAIGzQA2UHBxCnBsBMCh1nstp2i97e-2HMZA36CGFRlQ3HBpwB0C4ADklmgAAxHtMCMTIUgAWj0dcCGsDgoh0bNX02NJ3TWDZ9m2F0RQufDSNHC4v0QmMIDjFRp1lKitnnTdF1KEitg3RUt1LPVy0NTIqxfHi0mQdDL2LRIeBvR1cI-Tc6L7P1B3-YNRzDE8ICnD0kQiKgamgeAkGQOI2y6P5KFlAB3NpcQ6GCVhUXRgG4EAAH4JkjUIbjuWILKshgQGeHBpWsb52UBYFQQhHYQr+QzbhRE4q0xbEFLYSlZDZUkKSpGkW3pRkTOSDgZOvAUuTmJReSuKgBTClsBX0UKFks9qwqwSUGEi1p5WsBzBCc5AAFYAAYCHczzVS4bg0TAQoWIGPM0ysZARrGgAmSbJu8JMzzq7gFmGxy0VYABGfaZp0DyRIWpaVqTNi0k27bLuQAB2cbDuuUIgA) for viewing this code.

My goal is to end up with an object that lifts the `formatValue` function from `items`, and injects it into `columns` at the appropriate key.  The complexity I'm running into is that the typing around `formatValue` is different for each key, and I cannot figure out the right way to join them such that types are preserved.

```js
const result = {
  id: {
    width: 50,
    align: 'right',
    formatValue: ({ value }) => String(value),
  },
  product: {
    width: 200,
    formatValue: ({ value }) => value,
  },
  earnings: {
    width: 100,
    align: 'right',
    formatValue: ({ value, item }) => Intl.NumberFormat('en-us', { style: 'currency', currency: item.currency }).format(value),
  },
  currency: {
    width: 75,
    formatValue: ({ value }) => value,
  },
};
```

**Edit**: Adding a little more clarity here, hopefully this helps.

I attempted to approach joining these objects by using a typed version of `Object.fromEntries` to iterate over each key in the `items`/`columns` variables.  The problem with this approach is that each property's value (specifically around `formatValue`) becomes a union of all possible types rather than maintaining the intended underlying types.

Here's an [updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjmAPAFQDTIBqAfMgN4CwAUMsiHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDc1tACYQ2CLgAcwwAPYhWHLiD4DkMaVAaZCcADYBXFsgAU4uFEZtWZZADddB1oV7JgkBqxzIAvgEpkAXlIFHn4qL2pqMABPcRQAYT0oKAgQBCiA5AByAFVUABFM5AAfLLiAQQLQ6lBIWEQUAEk3chVgQVYQPQYAI2hQ2nEoaUE9BDB5ThCVCDMQHks6Lt6ofuQEROTUqNYEpJS01YB6Q+QIMAQAOmpwqkiYlHRMNlxSf3JkAG0ABRcQZABrCBRaQwZA4AC6rEe2HwYO+4NIXiqVGOYIAFsA2C4sWA0SgYMAoBxkNJugArCBjZC4zDIBqZBi-WoiSCCX5raQ9UA8C686gIWTE1wQBgLaHPJoi14tGgudoy2i0ehMViZBoFPAqIQiMTASQyORZbJzACOBjlKSkBOgqnUyDg7F0IhcbgumU1stoag0WnshiM1js+hQvgCpHQim4RiDBh8HtoXnjyEGw1G4wViuVhkyXyGIzG7q1yGEogkUlkqpweLojBQIOp1ZT+bA7GkOkEbqTXvUmjA2mDrADtj93j8gWHwaTiems3mViLWdVAFFZ0o2IXPcWdWWDZXq4I2zozBPzTMoCAIGzQA2UHBxCnBsBMCh1nstp2i97e-2HMZA36CGFRlQ3HBpwB0C4ADklmgAAxHtMCMTIUgAWj0dcCGsDgoh0bNX02NJ3TWDZ9m2F0RQufDSNHC4v0QmMIDjFRp1lKitnnTdF1KEitg3RUt1LPVy0NTIqxfHi0mQdDL2LRIeBvR1cI-Tc6L7P1B3-YNRzDE8ICnD0kQiKgamgeAkGQOI2y6P5KFlAB3NpcQ6GCVhUXRgG4EAAH4JkjUIbjuWILKshgQGeHBpWsb52UBYFQQhHYQr+QzbhRE4q0xbEFLYSlZDZUkKSpGkW3pRkTOSDgZOvAUuTmJReSuKgBTClsBX0UKFks9qwqwSUGEi1p5WsBzBCc5AAFYAAYCHczzVS4bg0TAQoWIGPM0ysZARrGgAmSbJu8JMzzq7gFmGxy0VYABGfaZp0DyRIWpaVqTNi0k27bLuQAB2cbDuuZFUUg6Q7LpLa4HAalpGQMlpGvXERBQICsRTbhzAYXtgAQXQdCiAg7IxXDkwq6AbHk6JYjYBrApQJdwC4EQXgyWzaA+ABpGKgXrCEUJ8z42YIHB2fBcF-I+WLufBD5RaMiAAA9xHUVrBRbbgzjpyZnTeXBTjlyAQEELECspMBiCMAqPDHUgAHlyRNi5LQZthzfJPw4CxDWnZeZFmuJGrulAGS3jVsBPeAEQjDa6y2B8C5NHEIwjA+a12wIYQYHBK2-yLBr067ZBUTE6kYnk+tVJ-FAD2dEBpBbQZEagGwUARkkFtAXRi6CvFkka-jy-U8jRWT8P23BWiELUydmKYqgfGRIA) with what I'm attempting to do.  Note the wrong typing on the resultant `formatValue` function.

Comment: You just want the type?  Then you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAPZ1N) where `Result<T>` combines `Column` and `formatValue()` appropriately.  Is that what you're looking for? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I'm trying to figure out how to join the actual objects while respecting the types.  I attempted to use a typed version of `Object.fromEntries` to iterate over each key in items/columns, but the problem is that each property's value becomes a union of possible types rather than maintaining the intended underlying type.

Comment: You can implement that function however you like that works (e.g., `Object.entries()`) but you'll need something like a type assertion to convince the compiler that the types are as you expect.  If the answer posted below by the other user doesn't work for you I'll take another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to extend *Column* instances with a *formatValue* property that contains the value from the corresponding *Stat* instance while still retaining then *Item's* property type.

The example below will do just that, making the *value* property used in the returned object's *formatValue's* arguments be the same type of corresponding item with the same key.

```
interface FormattedColumn<T, V> extends Column {
  formatValue: (params: { value: V; item: T }) => string;
}
type ColumnsWithFormat<T> = { [P in keyof T]: FormattedColumn<T, T[P]> };

function extendColumns<T>(columns: Columns<T>, stats: Stats<T>): ColumnsWithFormat<T> {
  const columnsWithFormat: Partial<ColumnsWithFormat<T>> = {};
  for (const key in stats) {
    columnsWithFormat[key] = { ...columns[key], formatValue: stats[key].formatValue };
  }
  return columnsWithFormat as ColumnsWithFormat<T>;
  // Alternative with Object.entries.
  // return (Object.entries(stats) as [keyof T, Stats<T>[keyof T]][])
  //    .reduce((acc, [key, stat]) => ({ ...acc, [key]: { ...columns[key], formatValue: stat.formatValue }}), 
  //      {} as Partial<ColumnsWithFormat<T>>) as ColumnsWithFormat<T>;
}

const result = extendColumns(columns, items);

// formatValue: (params: { value: Currency; item: Item; }) => string
result.currency.formatValue({ item: { currency: 'USD', earnings: 1, id: 1, product: 'abc' }, value: 'USD' });
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had to tweak the exact implementation slightly for my actual use case, but this essentially did the trick.